# Getting variable name from a string for ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I was wondering if it was possible to retrieve a variable name from a string in Java, but that can be used in an ArrayList. I have read the countless posts on StackOverflow about doing this, using maps, for example, but I keep getting "The constructor ArrayList(String) is undefined." All I want to do is this:

```
 int first = 1; //These can change between each other, depending on the circumstances, 
                  like second could equal 3.
 int second = 2;
 int third = 3;
 int fourth = 4;

            List<String> player1List = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(player1));
            List<String> player2List = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(player2));
            List<String> player3List = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(player3));
            List<String> player4List = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(player4));

                String FirstString = "player" + first + "List";
                String SecondString = "player" + second + "List";
                String ThirdString = "player" + third + "List";
                String FourthString = "player" + fourth + "List";

                List<String> fusedPlayer1 = new ArrayList<String>(FirstString);
                fusedPlayer1.addAll(FourthString);

                List<String> fusedPlayer1 = new ArrayList<String>(SecondString);
                fusedPlayer1.addAll(ThirdString);
```

`player1`, `player2`, `player3` and `player4` are all strings. Now, you may be wondering why I want to do this, but this is just an example, and in my actual program, there is a better reason for using this method. I'm a very beginner at Java, so please forgive my lack of knowledge...
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

New code :

```
int first = 1; //These can change between each other, depending on the circumstances, 
                      like second could equal 3.
     int second = 2;
     int third = 3;
     int fourth = 4;

                List<String> player1List = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(player1));
                List<String> player2List = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(player2));
                List<String> player3List = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(player3));
                List<String> player4List = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(player4));

                    String FirstString = "player" + first + "List";
                    String SecondString = "player" + second + "List";
                    String ThirdString = "player" + third + "List";
                    String FourthString = "player" + fourth + "List";

             Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
             map.put(FirstString,  "player" + first   + "List");
             map.put(SecondString, "player" + second  + "List");
             map.put(ThirdString,  "player" + third   + "List");
             map.put(FourthString, "player" + fourth  + "List");

        List<String> fusedPlayer1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        fusedPlayer1.add(map.get(FirstString));
        fusedPlayer1.add(map.get(FourthString));

        List<String> fusedPlayer2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        fusedPlayer2.add(map.get(SecondString));
        fusedPlayer2.add(map.get(ThirdString));
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll be sure to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
List<String> fusedPlayer1 = new ArrayList<String>(FirstString);
```

Is telling Java that you want to invoke the `ArrayList` constructor that takes a `String` as an argument. The problem is that `ArrayList` has no such constructor, hence "The constructor ArrayList(String) is undefined.".

The `ArrayList` class provides three constructors, and they have the following signatures:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) { ... }

public ArrayList() { ... }

public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) { ... }
```

What I suspect you're trying to do is to create the `ArrayList` with the argument `String` as an initial element. As it's a single `String` rather than a group of `String`s, your best bet is to do the following:

```
List<String> fusedPlayer1 = new ArrayList<String>();
fusedPlayer1.add(FirstString);
```

It should also be noted that as of Java 7, you no longer need to specify the type twice, so you can write the following:

```
List<String> fusedPlayer1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

The compiler then uses *type inference* to work out what the generic type of the `ArrayList` should be.

Based on some of your comments, a `Map` construct seems more suited to your needs:

```
Map<Integer, LinkedList<String>> players = new HashMap<>();

players.put(1, player1List);
players.put(2, player2List);
players.put(3, player3List);
players.put(4, player4List);
```

Then when you need to access, for example, `player3List`, you simply do:

```
players.get(3); // This will return the LinkedList associated with the Integer 3.
```

Lastly, as you can see from the syntax colouring above, the conventions for Java are that your variable names should either be:

- `namedInCamelCase`, that is, the first word is all lower case and the first letter of subsequent words is upper case, or
- `NAMED_IN_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES` if the variable is both `final` and `static`.

Class names should be in `CamelCaseWithAnInitialCapital`.

Comment: However, just to be sure, what this is doing is `FirstString` is linked to `player + first + List`, which finally is linked to `player1List`, correct?

Comment: @PhilipBecker All you're doing is creating a `String` that contains the text `"playerXList"` and then storing that `String` object inside the `ArrayList` - that's all.

Comment: Would there be a way to make the program know that, for example, the string containing player1List is referencing the list named player1List?

Comment: @PhilipBecker Not easily. Your best bet would be to store each `LinkedList` in a `Map`, keyed either by a `String` or an `Integer`, then you could access the appropriate `LinkedList` by using that key.

Comment: @PhilipBecker No - you haven't put anything into the `Map` in order to be able to get it back out. The `Map` also needs to be of the correct type, so something like `Map<String, List<String>>` rather than `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: I've done the changes that you've suggested, and added the `map.put` statements, but now `map.put` is giving me: "The method put(String, List<String>) in the type Map<String,List<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)".

Comment: @PhilipBecker Make sure you're passing in the correct stuff. You should be passing in a key as the first parameter, so that would be `FirstString1 or the like, then you need to pass in the matching `LinkedList` as the second parameter (the value), which would be `player1List`.

Comment: That's what I did, yet I'm still getting those errors... `map.put(FirstString, "player" + first + "List");`

Comment: @PhilipBecker That's because `"player" + first + "List"` is just a String. It needs to be the variable `player1List`.

Comment: But the point of the code is to reference playerXList, like if first is equal to 3, then player + first + List is player3List, and then references player3List.

Comment: @PhilipBecker But it won't - it'll only ever be a String, nothing more. There's no reason you can't use that String as the key to the real variable in a `Map` though - that's what I'm suggesting you do.

Comment: So it's impossible to get a variable name out of a string?

Comment: @PhilipBecker You can do it using Java's built-in Reflection libraries but I would avoid those unless absolutely necessary. Reflection lets you do all sorts of nasty things that you normally shouldn't be able to do, and it's generally slower than doing things the usual way to boot.

Comment: How would you use reflection, in my case?

Comment: @PhilipBecker That depends what you want to do with it once you've got the field

Comment: String to variable name, so that I can use it in the fusedPlayer1 and fusedPlayer2 ArrayLists.

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more detail about what you're trying to do and *why* you're trying to do it the way you are. I'd be extremely surprised if you genuinely needed to use Reflection for what you ultimately need to accomplish. That also probably belongs in a separate question too, as it's going out of scope of the original question here.

Comment: Actually, I would like to know where I can download Reflection, just so I can see how it is.

Comment: Reflection is part of the standard Java packages. You can find it under `java.lang.reflect`, no additional download necessary.

Comment: Great! Then I'll try using that to solve my problem. Thank you very much for all of your help! It's very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You either need to store your lists in a map or you use a two dimmensional array where the first dimension is the index. Using variable names would also be possible with reflection (at least if your variables are fields), but this is extremly bad practize.

This is how you would generate 4 lists and address them with an integer variable:

```
int first = 0;
List<String>[] lists = new List<String>[4];
lists[0] = new ArrayList<String>();
lists[1] = new ArrayList<String>(); ...
List<String> firstList = lists[first];
```